# Is it possible to have a single build machine that can build different flavors of the same app for different customers?

Tags: ios, xcode

The company I work for is creating an iOS app that will be skinned differently depending upon who the customer is (there will only be a handful of different customers, who are actually  network operators).

Thus 99% of the code is identical, what will differ is the app icons, images, text and maybe a few code tweaks here and there, such that each app is branded according to each operators corporate guidelines etc.

The end result will be a set of different apps that effectively just differ in appearance but are actually all doing the same thing.

However as these are different apps, I'm assuming each customer will have to actually sign up for an iOS account and submit their particular version of the app themselves to the app store and that is not something we would be able to do for them. Is this correct?

Assuming it is, then I'm wondering if we can still do the building of the apps for them and just give the built version to them to submit, and I'm thinking of collecting together all the different apps in one workspace where the code can be shared but different apps are generated when built.

As they will be different apps they will need to be signed with different certificates and profiles etc. This in itself is easy to do - each app could for example have its own target.

But my question is, is it possible to put different profiles and certificates etc. on a single build machine in order to build all these different apps? The reason I ask is because in one of Apple's XCode videos the commentator says something like: "Builds need to run on a build machine as a user who has accepted the license agreement".

Is this something that is going to be possible, could one build machine create different apps using different sets of profiles/certificates for different customer companies?

Comment: Can you edit the question so that it's not an "Is it possible?" question? As worded, an answer of "Yes, it's possible" or "No, it's not possible" would be acceptable, and that's obviously not what you're looking for here. It's also not useful in a search in it's present form. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.  I work at a company where we submit apps both to our own App Store and to the stores of multiple clients, and we have successfully built with multiple certificates on the same machine many times.

You will need the client's Distribution Certificate and their Provisioning Profile for the application, but yes, everything will work fine.

---

Ah, and to answer the first question you asked which I forgot about--yes, each client would need their own iTunes Connect account, but you *could* set it up for them.  They could create the account and then give you the password, you could do the uploading for them, and then they could reset the password if they're concerned with security.